# Angular 5 Material Snackbar panelClass config

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to add a [panelClass](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/api#additional_classes) config to the [Angular Material Snackbar](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview).

I wrote the following code, by following documentations from the official websites.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSnackBar, MatSnackBarConfig } from "@angular/material";
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'snack-bar-component-example',
  templateUrl: './snack-bar-component-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['./snack-bar-component-example.css']
})
export class SnackBarComponentExample implements OnInit {

  constructor(public snackBar: MatSnackBar) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  saveButtonClick = () =>{
    this.snackBar.open("This is a message!", "ACTION", {
      duration: 3000,
      panelClass: ["font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;"]
    });
  }
}
```

I have already binded the event to the HTML Button.When I am removing the `panelClass` config, then the duration config is working fine.
I am importing a Google Font (Open Sans) and trying to apply the font to the Snackbar. However, I am receiving an error:

```
ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'add' on 'DOMTokenList': The token provided ('font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;') contains HTML space characters, which are not valid in tokens.
```

Maybe, I am not able to understand how to use `panelClass`. Even, when I am trying to add this,

```
panelClass: ["color:white;"];
```

It is still showing the error:

```
ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'add' on 'DOMTokenList': The token provided ('color: white;') contains HTML space characters, which are not valid in tokens.
```

How can I fix this error and get things working? Please help.

**PS:** I am aware with the `extraClasses` config. But, I don't want to use it as it is written in the documentation that it will soon be deprecated.

**PPS:**: It is working fine with the duration config.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In your component SnackBarComponentExample try:

```
saveButtonClick = () =>{
  let config = new MatSnackBarConfig();
  config.duration = 5000;
  config.panelClass = ['red-snackbar']
  this.snackBar.open("This is a message!", "ACTION", config);
}
```

Where **`'red-snackbar'`** is a class in your apps main **`styles.css`** file. Strangely I was unable to get the **`config.panelClass`** to work when I was referencing my components associated css file, but once I put the class into the main **`styles.css`** file my styles were applied correctly to the snackBar.

Comment: alternatively: 
`this.snackBar.open("This is a message!", "ACTION", {duration: 500, panelClass: ['red-snackbar']});`

Comment: ::ng-deep .error-snackbar {
  background-color: fuchsia !important;
}
Worked for me

Comment: @Lucky it may work for now, but I would advise against using that method. Angular has deprecated `/deep/, >>>, and ::ng-deep`. Support for them will eventually be completely dropped.

Comment: The styles in your component css file are isolated meaning you can't inject them to lower level components, that's why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 9):

In my case all above doesn't work. It starts working when I add `!important` in `css`:

```
.error-snackbar {
  background-color: fuchsia !important;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In angular 7 using ::ng-deep in front of class worked for me.

```
::ng-deep  .snackBar-fail {
    color: #ffffff !important;
    background-color: #cc3333 !important;
}
```

Comment: I like this better than putting it in the global css file as this is related to this component and should be kept in the same place where all the other styles are

Comment: @Wildhammer this is the same as putting it in the global css file. From the Angular docs "`Any style with ::ng-deep applied becomes a global style`" Also this make work in Angular V7, but ng-deep has been deprecated in the latest versions of Angular.

Answer (score 3):

panelClass is defined as

> panelClass: string | string[]
>
> Extra CSS classes to be added to the snack bar container.

It is used to add a class, not a style.

Imagine the size of the array if you had to put complex css styling in there.

So you need to define your style in a css and only then you can apply a class to the bar:

```
panelClass: ['first-class', 'second-class'];
```

Comment: So, what's the difference between `extraClasses` and `panelClass`?
And now, I am passing CSS classes, instead of CSS statements, yet it's not working.

Comment: extraClasses is deprecated. Can you create a plunker to demonstrate your bug?

Answer (score 0):

In the Angular 13 if you need to change the font size add this to css class:

```
::ng-deep .snackbar_ * {
    font-size: 22px !important;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
this.snackBar.open('Ho ho ho', 'Okey',{
    duration:200000,
    panelClass: 'main-snackbar'
});
```

```css
.main-snackbar{
  .mdc-snackbar__surface{
    background-color: #72716d !important;
    color: white!important;
  }
  .mat-mdc-snack-bar-actions{
    button{
      color: white!important;
    }
  }
}
```