# MatSnackBar panelClass doesnt read styling class

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to insert a scss class into MatSnackBar panelClass. but it didnt working. fyi, the verticalPosition & horizontalPosition work fine. heres my TS:

```
 openSnackBar(message: string, action: any) {
    this.snackBar.open(message, action, {
      duration: 2000,
      verticalPosition: 'top',
      horizontalPosition: 'center',
      panelClass: ['alert-red'],
    });
 }
```

and heres my Scss:

```
.alert-red{
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Can you create stackblitz link to reproduce the issue?>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**EDIT:**
It seems to work if you prefix your class with the following `::ng-deep snack-bar-container` (see [this](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4522#issuecomment-346181879) comment). So your component SCSS file should look like this:

```
::ng-deep snack-bar-container.alert-red{
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

**WORKAROUND:** See post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48290503/4606040), it seems that you need to put the style in your applications `styles.scss` file and not in your components SCSS file.

Check [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-nrjfiu?file=styles.scss) stackblitz, the style works in the `styles.scss`, but not when you comment it out and leave it in the `app.component.scss`. Not sure if this is a bug or intended behaviour.

Comment: Indeed, placing the styling in the `styles.scss` fixed the issue, I tried to place it in the customs.scss which usually sets the styling for the whole application but it had no effect

Answer (score 2):

You have to set `encapsulation` property for the component:

Like :

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core'; // import ViewEncapsulation from core

@Component({
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None  // Set ViewEncapsulation.None for encapsulation property
})
```

and add CSS classes in HTML file as:

```
this.snackBar.open("message", {
      panelClass:['customClass']
});
```

In CSS file:

```
.customClass{
  color: red;
}
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-anzddh)

Comment: I wouldn't really do it like this because sometimes the ViewEncapsulation leaks into other components and it does more harm than good

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I just added !important after the properties defined in my css class to override some default styling. So like:

```
    .alert-red{
      padding: 20px !important;
      background-color: red !important;
      color: white !important;
    }
```

Comment: Using `!important` is usually a bad practice. Should be used with care.

Comment: Of course, but as "styling" Material elements is basically overriding the default properties, I think it's often necessary. It's only bad practice when you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: In case of overriding angular  Material components, I would do it using the "deprecated" `::ng-deep` within specific component stylesheet which should work fine or would overwrite it globally in `styles.css` (usually using higher specificity for more granular control when certain components needs to be styled) or if it possible then ideally using the official theming guide https://material.angular.io/guide/theming (although this proved to be complicated and not worth the effort most of the time).

Answer (score 1):

```
    $snackBarContainerColorError: #d32f2f;
$snackBarContainerColorSuccess: #43a047;

mat-snack-bar-container.success {
  .mdc-snackbar__surface {
    background-color: $snackBarContainerColorSuccess !important;
  }
}


mat-snack-bar-container.error {
  .mdc-snackbar__surface {
    background-color: $snackBarContainerColorError !important;
  }
}
```

this is working on 16.0.4

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error today and I resolved it by using these specific classes in the styles.sccs:

```
.mat-mdc-snack-bar-container {
  &.success-snackbar {
    --mdc-snackbar-container-color: green;
  }
}

.mat-mdc-snack-bar-container {
  &.error-snackbar {
    --mdc-snackbar-container-color: red;
  }
}
```

And in the panel I used either snackbar-success or snackbar-error.