# Angular Material Snackbar position

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, snackbar

I'd like to place material snackbar under my header (height of it is 60px).

The problem is that verticalPosition places snackbar to the top and covers header.
I'd tried to add "margin-top: 75px", but the above area was unclickable. (there's an overlay)

[image]

I can't change the style of cdk-overlay-pan because i have other dialogs.

Comment: Using `!important` with margin-top in CSS should help. Can you produce minimal copy of your code so it would be easier for us to debug.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try this :

1. Create a global `css` class to modify style of your `Snackbar` component.
2. Set `panelClass` property in config options.

Add this style declaration in global `styles.scss` :

```
.my-custom-snackbar {
  margin: 0 !important;
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  top: 60px;
}
```

Then when `SnackBar` is opened :

```
this.snackbar.open('Hello the world!', '', {
  panelClass: 'my-custom-snackbar'
});
```

Answer (score 4):

From the api documentation (https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/api):

Parameters for the "Open" method of MatSnackBar:

```
message (string) - The message to show in the snackbar.
action (string) - The label for the snackbar action.
config? (MatSnackBarConfig<any>) - Additional configuration options for the snackbar.
```

MatSnackBarConfig has amongst the following properties:

```
horizontalPosition: MatSnackBarHorizontalPosition - The horizontal position to place the snack bar.
verticalPosition: MatSnackBarVerticalPosition - The vertical position to place the snack bar.
```

To see that in action, you could easily create a component, inject the MatSnackBar and
write a open method to pass your config.

Here is a little example how my Snackbar component looks like:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mat-snackbar',
  templateUrl: './mat-snackbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mat-snackbar.component.scss']
})
export class MatSnackbarComponent {

  constructor(public snackBar: MatSnackBar) {}

  openSnackBar(message: string, action: string, className: string) {
    this.snackBar.open(message, action, {
      duration: 9000,
      verticalPosition: 'top',
      horizontalPosition: 'center',
      panelClass: [className],
    });
  }

}
```

I call it from my http Interceptor like that:

```
constructor(private SnackbarComponent: MatSnackbarComponent) {}
...
...
// Something wrong happened
this.SnackbarComponent.openSnackBar(errorMessage, 'Close', 'error-snackbar');
```

In my Style.css file i added a css class for this snackbar, which is also the last parameter for the openSnackBar method.
This was just a workaround because some css inside my mat-snackbar.component.css does not work. I found some other solution with `::ng-deep` here: [MatSnackBar panelClass doesnt read styling class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53883827/matsnackbar-panelclass-doesnt-read-styling-class).
You have to use it carefully because there is no ViewEncapsulation if you use the style in styles.css. But for me it was much cleaner to do that like this.

my styles.css looks like:

```
.error-snackbar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
}
```

Comment: the problem is that I wanna to place it a little lower than at the top

Comment: if you use "margin-top" you don't have an opportunity to click on the area which is above of notification because there's an overlay

Comment: With my example you can add any CSS that fits to your needs. But in general it's not a good practice to add global styles to work around angulars view encapsulation. So if you need some special behavior It's often better to write your own component.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply margin-top to the parent div of `snack-bar-container` element.
Use this CSS (you may need to apply none for the View.Encapsulation depending on your structure.)

```
.mat-snack-bar-handset {
    margin-top: 75px !important; 
}
```