# How should Angular 7 Material `panelClass` property be used?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

[Angular 5 Material Snackbar panelClass config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47901127/angular-5-material-snackbar-panelclass-config) Is a very similar question only there is a slew of guesswork involved and I am struggling to make any of it work in Angular 7.

[The API](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/api) is pretty simple. Provide a `string | string[]` which I presume are class names.

But where do you define these styles and what is the syntax involved? Is there a standard method?

A naive guess would be to put `panelClass: ['my-class']` then in `styles.css`

```css
.my-class{
   text-align: center;
}
```

But it doesn't appear to be so simple. Especially when I look at `ViewEncapsulation`. Snackbars appear to be global styles and I don't really know the technique which wouldn't violate scoped styles.

[ng-deep](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) is leaving us but they mention:

> As such we plan to drop support in Angular (for all 3 of /deep/, >>>
>   and ::ng-deep). Until then ::ng-deep should be preferred for a broader
>   compatibility with the tools.

I haven't seen a depricated feature be recommended and not sure what the future holds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The DOM for components that use the overlay like snack bars and dialogs is not a descendent of the DOM for the parent component that 'launches' the overlay component. Therefore, because of encapsulation, trying to style it from the parent component's CSS/Sass is futile even with deep selectors. So that style - the class specified using the `panelClass` option - needs to exist in the global style sheet. So your 'naive guess' is correct - it is that simple.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed to know.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @G. Tranter!

Answer (score 1):

DOM for Snackbar is not a child element of the component being called, so because of this reason, ng-deep is used if the class selector is being used.

```
      this._snackBar.open('Hello World', 'Close', {
        duration: 30000,
        panelClass: [custom-style],
      });
```

component.css

```
::ng-deep .custom-style{  background-color:brown;  color:white;}
```

In this method you can even pass different strings to change the styling of the Snackbar. by replacing **custom-style** and implementing different css stylings in the related CSS file of the component (or global - style.css if you want to make it globally.)

Source - https://www.cloudhadoop.com/angular-material-snackbar-examples/